# React state console logs updated state although while drag&dropping later on it uses previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am developing an application in react typescript environment and I faced a problem which I cannot resolve on my own. Whenever I try to set state to its initial value I get my UI updated although console.log(state) would still return previous state. When I console.log it using useEffect with dependency to my state I get the updated value printed out.

My biggest concern is how can that happen that react 'saves' previous state somewhere and uses it when user is performing a drag and drop interaction.

```
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(initialState);

  function clearBoard(){
    updateBoard(initialState)
    console.log(board)
  }

  function updateBoard(board: UnitHex[][]){
    setBoard(board);
    //some side actions 
  }

   const draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
  const droppableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droppable");

  function dragStart(event: any) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  }

  function dragOver(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tempBoard: UnitHex[][] = board;
    console.log("inside drop fn")
    console.log(tempBoard);

    //drop logic
    
    updateBoard(tempBoard);
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }


   useEffect(() => {
    droppableElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
      element.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    });

    draggableElements.forEach((element) => {
      element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    });
    console.log(board)
  }, [board]);
```

Does anyone know what's going on?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: React's state is not updated immediately because state update is asynchronous. You cannot expect `console.log` will print the latest state value for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not React that's storing the old information, it's your code. :-)

You're getting elements directly from the DOM during the main run of your component function:

```
const draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const droppableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droppable");
```

...which is not how you should do things in React. Then you're adding event handlers to those elements:

```
useEffect(() => {
    droppableElements.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
        element.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    });

    draggableElements.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    });
    console.log(board);
}, [board]);
```

...and never removing old handlers. So the elements keep the old handler **and** the new one. The old handler runs first, does `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, and that prevents the new handler from running.

At a minimum:

1. Don't grab the elements during render, do it in an effect afterward
2. Remove old handlers with a cleanup callback

Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
    const droppableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droppable");

    droppableElements.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
        element.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    });

    draggableElements.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    });
    
    return () => { // Cleanup callback
        droppableElements.forEach((element) => {
            element.removeEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
            element.removeEventListener("drop", drop);
        });

        draggableElements.forEach((element) => {
            element.removeEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
        });
    };
}, [board]);
```

That way, only the up-to-date version of `dragOver` and `drop` will be hooked up on the elements.

But again, using DOM methods like `document.querySelectorAll` is usually not best practice in React code. There are rare exceptions; drag and drop may be one of them, although handling it at the component level with global elements seems a bit off.